# Django is putting empty string by default while expecting it to be null in DB column

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-models, django-orm

I am using `postgresql` version 10.6 with my `Django` 2.1 application. The problem is that when I am using `null=True` in my model field it is translating to **empty string ('')** in database column as default where I am trying default it as `null`.

In my following code sample `image` column should be `null`:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='profile_pics', null=True, blank=True)
```

And I am calling this class from a `signal` like this:

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_profile(sender, **kwargs):
    if kwargs.get('created') is True:
        Profile.objects.create(user=kwargs.get('instance'))
```

In this snapshot you can see that `image` column is inserting as empty string instead of `null`

[image]

I have also tried to use default value for my model field as:

```
image = models.ImageField(default=None, upload_to='profile_pics', null=True, blank=True)
```

but it doesn't work either.

Comment: Unless you really need to store `null` in the field, it would be easiest to use `blank=True`, allow `null=False` by default, and let Django store empty strings instead of `null`. Django added an `allow_empty` option to `CharField` to make it easier to save nulls instead of empty strings, but `ImageField` doesn't inherit from `CharField`, so you would have to implement that functionality yourself.

Comment: @Alasdair Absolutely agree. I'd also store just empty strings, otherwise you might run into a case where you have NULL for some entries and an empty string for other entries.

Answer (score 0):

```
image = models.ImageField(upload_to='profile_pics', null=True)
```

remove the `blank=True`

Comment: Sorry it doesn't work, as @Alasdair said in comment of question I think it need to implement manually

Answer (score -1):

**Null:** It is database-related. Defines if a given database column will accept null values or not.

**Blank:** It is validation-related. It will be used during forms validation when calling form.is_valid().

The default values of null and blank are False.

You should remove `blank=True`

Comment: Why is this answer downvoted? The information provided is correct.

Comment: I think they gave me downvoted for writing the same thing as the first answer. But rather than type 'remove `blank=True`', I wanted to explain the difference between `null` and `blank`.

Comment: The OP is running `Profile.objects.create(user=kwargs.get('instance'))`, so there is no model validation. Therefore it makes no difference whether or not `blank=True`.

Comment: I know that there is no model validation. I just want to explain the general purpose of null and blank. Read the docs.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/fields/

Comment: *I just want to explain the general purpose of null and blank.* - that's fine, although I don't think it's really what the OP was asking about. I downvoted because you say *You should remove `blank=True`*, which will not change the behaviour of seeing `''` instead of `null` in the database.